# how to get the Camera track setup from a 360 video?

Tags: camera, tracking, panoramic, movie-clip-editor

I'm trying to overlay 3D scene with a 360 video.
The 360 camera in the video is fixed, so I don't actually need the tracker for stabilization, what I'm trying to do, is to render my objects in 3D view, then overlay the outcome on top of the 360 video in the Sequence Editor. 
I created the markers in Movie Clip Editor, Solved the Camera Motion, selected 3 markers and hit Floor in the Solve Panel. The problem is, I can't get the floor to be in the right position, the result change when I select different markers to define the floor. Please check the images. I thought to try to set the floor manually, add few cubes and eye ball the camera, and this might work for this example, but what if I'm working on a different scene where I actually need the 3D camera to track the movement of the 360 video? All I can think about, is that I'm missing something that I need to check in the Movie Clip Editor, to tell Blender that this is a 360 video.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I do not understand why you are using the tracker. If the camera is not moving there is no way to reconstruct the scene.

Comment: Yes, probably I'm just being dumb, do you think this would work for a moving camera? I mean would I be able to get the floor positioned right if I use a different footage where the camera is moving? @cegaton

Comment: (sorry for the typos... I'll try again) The tracker has no way to infer any of the geometry from the image unless there is some paralax. Meaning points moving at different rates based on their distance to the camera. On static images there is no point of tracking static objects. Probably you could to use the 360 video as background on a scene using it as environment texture with  equirectangular projection. Then set your geometry within that scene and render using a panoramic lens with equirectangular projection...

Comment: You are right, I was experimenting using the wrong example, I'll try to redo this using a footage with a moving camera. Many thanks for your help @cegaton